# Shading issue only occurs on a single frame in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shaders, shader-nodes

I have rendered a video with a red wave (plane with wave modifier), which moves around the earth. The shading is set so it gets darker (alpha decreased) with increasing distance from the earth's center. For one specific frame, the outside suddenly gets brighter. I can't find any changes in the shading parameters for this frame. Any ideas on why this might occur?
The problem does not occur with viewport rendering.
It does not occur in Eevee, but the wave looks generally worse there compared to Cycles.
Changing the time offset of the wave modifier does not change the #frame, where the problem occurs, so it must be unrelated to the precise shape of the wave.[image: Working frame one previous to the problematic one.]

The first picture shows one frame previous to the problem and the second one shows the problematic frame.
Any help is appreciated!

[image: Problematic frame with brighter edges.]

Comment: Well, just seeing two frames, no materials, no settings or anything else it is hard to tell what's the problem. Is there something else animated in the scene or just the wave?

Comment: You are right. I will make a copy of the file and delete the other objects, so I can either find the problem or come back with a small file only including the things directly related to the issue.